# Creating a Map with Custom Legend Using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I’m currently trying to display my data on a map as points. In fact I got two different data sets of two different studies which I’d like to combine on the map. But my first problem was where to find a map to use for my purpose.

```
#In the R graphics Cookbook I read about this code to create a map using the ggplot2 package
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
states_map <- mapd_data(“state”)
ggplot(states_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) +
geom_polygon(fill=”white”, colour=”black”) +

#Then I added the data of my two data sets and it worked perfectly fine.
geom_point(data = dat1, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, group= NA), shape=21, col = "black", fill=”red”,  size = dat1$var1) +
geom_point(data = dat2, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, group= NA), shape=21, col = "black", fill=”blue”,  size = dat2$var2)
```

Now I want to add two legends, one to explain the difference between the point colors and the other to explain the point size. Both data sets can share the same legend for the point size because Var1 and Var2 are on the same scale. But I don’t know how to add custom legends to a ggplot (I even don’t achieve to add any legend to the ggplot). It would be nice to have anything like legend()-function which adds a legend to a normal plot, but I think ggplot wasn’t programmed to solve problems like this on your own. Another approach to solve the problem could be to plot the map without using ggplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a legend then you have to map on an aesthetic, i.e. move `fill=...` and `size=...` inside `aes()`. After doing so you could set your desired fill colors via `scale_fill_manual`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
states_map <- map_data("state")

dat1 <- data.frame(longitude = -110, latitude = 35, var1 = 100)
dat2 <- data.frame(longitude = -90, latitude = 40, var2 = 200)
ggplot(states_map, aes(x=long, y=lat)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group=group), fill="white", colour="black") +
  geom_point(data = dat1, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = "dat1", size = var1), shape=21, col = "black") +
  geom_point(data = dat2, aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, fill = "dat2", size = var2), shape=21, col = "black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(dat1 = "red", dat2 ="blue"), labels = c(dat1 = "Data 1", dat2 ="Data 2"))
```

[image]